# Making API call and wanting to return true if user exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api

As the title says, I want to make an API call and depending if the user uuid appears, I want to return true.

Right now it returns false for every call, I'm thinking because the function is asynchronous and is returning false before it can do the comparison.

```
 function checkUserIsPerson(uuid: string): boolean {
        let IsPerson = false
        getPeople()
            .then((result: Array<peopleInfo>) => {
                result.forEach((person) => {
                    if (person.uuid === uuid) {
                        IsPerson = true      
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch()
        return isApprover
    }
```

```
 let isUser= false
    if (true) {
       let result= checkUserIsPerson(uuid)
       isUser = result
      
    }
```

Comment: two main issues. 1. you can't synchronously access the result of an asynchronous function. 2. returning a value in `.forEach` does nothing, since the return value doesn't go anywhere

Comment: You just asked this question a short while ago. The way to do what you want is to use `async` and `await`, or a callback.

Comment: Yeah well my question got closed and directed me to something that wasn't relevant. Async and await aren't working either.